# Control an embedded into website flash player with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, flash, controls, embedded-resource

I am trying to write few simple python scripts, which will allow me to control one of the Internet radio (which I listen) with an keybinded python scripts.

I am now able to connect and log into the website, I am able to get out the song data ( that is - all the data which are passed to the player).

I noticed, that the player is controlled with javascript, lets assume, that it's address is http://www.sitesite.com/player.swf

If the player can be controlled with javascript, then I think that there should be an way, to control it with python. If I am right, can someone please give me an example how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't control the player with Python, flash and javascript can talk to each other because of how the Flash player works when embedded in a web page. Sounds like you're circumventing the flash player anyhow, so why do you need to control a player you're not using?

Comment: Each song on this website has an id. I need to pass this id to the player. From what I have noticed, player will hash this id and grab the right song from the server - I don't know the hashing alogrithm, so I though that I will just use the player for the hashing.